# iframe content exceeds 100%

Tags: php, html, iframe, html-table

I have page with 3 iframes, the top iframe contains a table which I would like to fit to the size of the iframe.

When I use the code below the content in the iframe exceeds 100% and the only way to view all the content is to scroll which is no practical in this case.

How would I make the table contained in the iframe fit to 100% so that all the content is displayed within the iframes height?

Page 1:

```
<?php

$sysusrid = $_GET['sysusrid'];

?>

<html>

<table height="100%" border="0" width = "100%">

<tr><td width="70%" height="15%">

<iframe src="topbar.php?sysusrid=<?php echo $sysusrid;?>" height="90%" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><td width="30%">

</td></tr>

<tr><td height="55%">
<iframe src="middlebar.php" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</td></tr>


<tr><td height="20%">
<iframe src="bottombar.php" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</td></tr>


    </table>
</html>
```

tobbar.php

```
<html>

    <table height="100%" width="100%" border="0">

        <tr>

            <td width="20%"><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" style="border: 0px solid #000; max-width:100%; max-height:100%;"></td>

            <td width="55%" valign="top">

                <table height="50%" width="100%" border="0" >

                    <tr height="10%"><td bgcolor="#dd3a78" width="50%"><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">Credential</font></td><td bgcolor="#dd3a78" width="50%"><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">Value</font></td></tr>

                    <tr><td bgcolor=""><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">Client MSISDN</td><td bgcolor=""><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white"><?php echo $msisdn;?></td></tr>

                    <tr><td bgcolor="#525c68"><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">Date of Birth</td><td bgcolor="#525c68"><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white"><?php echo $dob;?></td></tr>

                    <tr><td bgcolor=""><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">Member Since</td><td bgcolor=""><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white"><?php echo $membersince;?></td></tr>



                    <tr><td bgcolor="#525c68"><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">sysUSRID</td><td bgcolor="#525c68"><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white"><?php echo $sysusrid;?></td></tr>

                    <tr><td bgcolor=""><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white">Name</td><td bgcolor=""><font face="verdana" size="2" color="white"><?php echo $name;?></td></tr>


                </table>


            </td>

            <td width="50%"></td>


        </tr>


    </table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change iframe height to the iframe content height you need to use JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').height = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+'px';
```

If you want to change table width inside iframe you can do that with contentWindow:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('table').style.width = '100%';
```

Comment: Hi, I am wanting to make the content fit the iframe (other way around).